# Where can I find documentation for benchmarkdotnet output

Tags: benchmarkdotnet

In the output from BenchmarkDotNet I have the following lines:

For the first benchmark

```
WorkloadResult  100: 1 op, 614219700.00 ns, 614.2197 ms/op
GC:  123 1 0 518085976 1
Threading:  2 0 1
```

For the second benchmark

```
WorkloadResult  73: 1 op, 464890400.00 ns, 464.8904 ms/op
GC:  14 1 0 59217312 1
Threading:  7469 0 1
```

What do the values in GC and Threading mean?

Answer (score 0):

You can find it at https://benchmarkdotnet.org/articles/guides/how-it-works.html and at https://adamsitnik.com/the-new-Memory-Diagnoser/#how-to-read-the-results.

To tell the long story short, you should care only about the results printed in the table, which are explained with Legend printed below it.